# Change title in wordpress in the end generation page

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem, I can not change title in theme template. Inside an unknown plugin set title for the main page and I am not able to change them. 
I use hooks in `function.php`:

```
function add_page_title() {
    echo 'My main Title';
}
add_filter('wp_title','add_page_title');
```

but its not working. Maybe I should set title in hooks "plugins_loaded" or any places?

Comment: Are you using any SEO plugin?

Comment: yes, this web site uses seo plugins, but they was written a different developer. I resolved this problem)) i change <title> on a <TITLE>.
I know it is not best way, but it is work)

Answer (score 1):

Filter must return a value. So modify your code as

```
function add_page_title($title,$seperator)
{
    return "my title";
}

add_filter('wp_title','add_page_title',50,2);
```

Comment: This means we need to set priority to add_filter to execute our function in last.

Comment: yes, I do. I add third param to function
add_filter('wp_title','add_page_title', 21474836);
but not helped

Comment: how I can disabled automatic generated Title?  I want insert title hard-code in header.php.

Comment: Are you using wp_title() in title tag of header.php?

Comment: yes, but, this function not working because, i deleted them for testing. and  set title in header.php <title>My title</title> and anyway title was changed unknown plugin((